# why is not the computer sensible to the JDK

Tags: android

I have downloaded the jdk-14.0.1 on my computer, but neither eclipse nor netbeans sense of its presence in my computer,and error messages appears like that:-for eclipse
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P86zO.png)

and for netbeans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgbXR.png)

these messages denotes that the jdk does not work, and by entering java -version in the cmd no thing appears, but at the same time the jdk is installed and reinstalled until I got bored, and it exists in C:\Program Files and the application exists in C:\Users\Dell\Downloads
now I am worried that the Android studio would not work also, my question is whether jdk is installed or not, and what to do to make the computer sensible to it. thanks a million.....

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Eclipse- JDK not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590355/eclipse-jdk-not-found) or [JDK was not found on the computer for NetBeans 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079472/jdk-was-not-found-on-the-computer-for-netbeans-6-5)

Comment: Yoe need to define JAVA_HOME in your environment variables (assuming you're on windows machine), here's how : https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/, as for Android studio, you need java 7(1.7) or 8  (1.8) as Android support only those 2 version of java out of the box, check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405689/2641657 for details